# Calculating the Point3Ds of a Cuboid around a Line

Tags: c#, algorithm, vector-graphics

There are two Point3D's (**A** and **B**) and I want to calculate the points of a cuboid (a,b,c ... h) surrounding the line between **A** and **B** like a hull:

[image]

There is one degree of freedom, the angle of the cuboid, because it can rotate around the line **AB**. I am not sure yet if this is a problem.

I tried to calculate a vector normal to **AB**, **D**, and then the cross product of **AB** ⨯ **AD** = **E**. In the code, **C** is **A** - **B** so its the offset parallel to **AB**.

I normalized these three vectors (**C**, **D** and **E**) and multiplied it with an offset to add / subtract them from **A** and **B**. It's not quite working yet.

**EDIT: see ja72's code for solution**

i also implemented a way of finding a normal vector:

```
                double ax = Vector3D.AngleBetween(E, new Vector3D(1, 0, 0));
                double ay = Vector3D.AngleBetween(E, new Vector3D(0, 1, 0));
                double az = Vector3D.AngleBetween(E, new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));

                ax = Math.Abs(ax - 90);
                ay = Math.Abs(ay - 90);
                az = Math.Abs(az - 90);

                if (ax <= ay & ax <= az)
                {
                    n = Vector3D.CrossProduct(E, new Vector3D(1, 0, 0));
                }
                else if (az <= ax && az <= ay)
                {
                    n = Vector3D.CrossProduct(E, new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    n = Vector3D.CrossProduct(E, new Vector3D(0, 1, 0));
                }
                n = normalize(n);
```

Comment: You also need to specify the orientation of the section about line _AB_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two direction vectors. One is along the line *AB* given by

```
Vector3D e = Normalize(B-A)
```

and one to descibe the "up" direction for the cross section. This can be given, or it can be calculated with the following algorithm (with preference towards +y)

```
if( e.X != 0 || e.Z != 0 ) 
{
    // choose direction perpendicular to line closest to +y direction
    Vector3D n = [-e.X*e.Y, e.X*e.X+e.Z*e.Z, -e.Z*e.Y];
} else {
    // if line along +y already then choose +z for up vector
    Vector3D n = [ 0, 0, 1];
}
```

Now you can calculate the 3rd direction to form a coordinate system

```
Vector3D k = Normalize( Cross(e,n) )
```

And you assemble the 3×3 rotation matrix that transforms local coordinates to world coordinates with

```
    | k.X  n.X  e.X |
R = | k.Y  n.Y  e.Y | 
    | k.Z  n.Z  e.Z |
```

The local coordinate have the direction along the line as +z such that

```
Point3D a = A + R*[w,h,0]
Point3D b = A + R*[-w,h,0]
Point3D c = A + R*[w,-h,0]
Point3D d = A + R*[-w,-h,0]

Point3D e = B + R*[w,h,0]
Point3D f = B + R*[-w,h,0]
Point3D g = B + R*[w,-h,0]
Point3D h = B + R*[-w,-h,0]
```

where `R*[x,y,z]` designates a matrix-vector multiplication, `w` and `h` are the width and height of the rectangular cross section, and `A`, `B` are the point *A* and *B* position vectors. Addition here between vectors is element by element.

---

I have checked the code in my own code and it works. `vec3` is alias for a 3D vector, `mat3` is alias for 3×3 matrix.

[image: Cube]

```
    vec3 u=(B-A).Normalized();

    vec3 n = vec3.O;
    if(Math.Abs(u.X)<=Math.Abs(u.Y)&&Math.Abs(u.X)<=Math.Abs(u.Z))
    {
        n=new vec3(u.Y*u.Y+u.Z*u.Z, -u.Y*u.X, -u.Z*u.X);
    }
    else if(Math.Abs(u.Y)<=Math.Abs(u.X)&&Math.Abs(u.Y)<=Math.Abs(u.Z))
    {
        n=new vec3(-u.X*u.Y, u.X*u.X+u.Z*u.Z, -u.Z*u.Y);
    }
    else if(Math.Abs(u.Z)<=Math.Abs(u.X)&&Math.Abs(u.Z)<=Math.Abs(u.Y))
    {
        n=new vec3(-u.X*u.Z, -u.Y*u.Z, u.X*u.X+u.Y*u.Y);
    }
    vec3 v=n.Cross(u);

    mat3 R=mat3.Combine(v, n, u);

    var a=A+R*new vec3(wt, ht, 0);
    var b=A+R*new vec3(-wt, ht, 0);
    var c=A+R*new vec3(wt, -ht, 0);
    var d=A+R*new vec3(-wt, -ht, 0);
    var e=B+R*new vec3(wt, ht, 0);
    var f=B+R*new vec3(-wt, ht, 0);
    var g=B+R*new vec3(wt, -ht, 0);
    var h=B+R*new vec3(-wt, -ht, 0);
```

Comment: I cannot make it more into code because I do not know the capabilities of your existing `Point3D` and `Vector3D` classes. Do they have operator overloading for `+` and `*`, can you do a cross product, etc?

Comment: Point3D is part of System.Windows.Media.Media3D, it also contains Vector3D which can do a cross product (see msdn)

Comment: Can you work with the algorithm above, or do you want me to break it down to more code and details.

Comment: This works mathematically, but obtaining the first normal is unstable when the line is close to y-axis--aligned. I would suggest orthogonalizing (1, 0, 0) or (0, 1, 0) with respect to e depending on whether abs(e.X) or abs(e.Y) is smaller.

Comment: I've implemented this algorithm, as far as i see is it working fine, just one thing, is the suggsestion of David Eisenstat considered in your code for Vector n?

Comment: I tried your suggsestions but they didn't work (see my picture)

Comment: @Stefan Did you normalize `n` (and not `e`, which is a no-op)? That shouldn't be the cause of the picture that you posted, though, since the length of `n` should be non-negligible. It would be helpful if you could post the complete revised code.

Comment: i've updated the code, what you can read there is what is producing the picture, the points of cuboids are all on the same plane

Comment: I rolled back the changes done to the post. They changed my algorithm.

Comment: I added my own `C#` code that checked for the correct results. Also I changed the normal vector calculation to favor whatever axis the line vector is _not_ along.

Comment: There's no point in checking the third axis, and you rolled back the change that made your new basis orthonormal.

Comment: My basis is orthonormal since `u·n=0` by design and `v=n×u`. I rolled in back because you changed by definition for `n` in a way that did not guarantee `u·n=0`.

Comment: okay, i found my mistake, i had an error with my matrix multiplikation function (messed up with indices). Funny that it worked some times...

Comment: Some elements must have been zero then, so the error did not show up.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a real piece of code, but I can give you an idea.

Ok, suppose you are already have a proper cuboid. I mean it has right width and height. 
Lets locate it on plane xy. After that you need to offset it to center (minus offset vector). The last thing is to rotate it according to your line rotation.

Again:

- Create cuboid and locate it on xy plane
- Move it according to your offsets
- Rotate it according to your line rotation

You may use matrix multiplication to achieve this transformations.

Comment: i could make a cuboid using length(A,B) + 2 * offset, then i could get the rotation of the Cuboid using Vector3D.AngleBetween(AB, (1,0,0)), Vector3D.AngelBetween(AB, (0,1,0)),... but im not sure how to rotate the points of the cuboid and how to move them according to my given offset

Comment: You are right. There could be a misunderstanding. The offset include two parts. The first one is your offset which you showed on the picture above. The second part is your line offset from the center.

Comment: Lets talk about the second. Your line has a end called as "a". You can determine how far is it from the center. Great. Now lets look at the second step in our great algorithm. Recall that at that point our cuboid lays on the plane xy. After out first offset x-axis pierce our cuboid as you showed at "top view", right? Now move your cuboid to the right (take distance from "a" to the center). That's it. Go to the step three.